# arm neon inline assembly output operand casting

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, neon

I am trying the following code:

```
glm::vec4 a;
asm volatile(
   "mov r1,#64 \t\n"
   "vld1.32 q4,[%[input]],r1 \n\t"
   :[input] "+r" (a.x))
```

But it generates error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address =0x0)".

If I change the operand type to float, the error disappears:

```
float a[4];
asm volatile(
   "mov r1,#64 \t\n"
   "vld1.32 q4,[%[input]],r1 \n\t"
   :[input] "+r" (a[0]))
```

Why does the type matter ? Is it possible to cast glm::vec4 to float here ? I tried a lot of different ways but neither work.

Comment: I don't speak ARM, but it appears that you are changing the value of a register (`r1`) without letting gcc know.  Shouldn't this be added as a clobber? And have you looked at the generated output (-S)?  If [input] happens to choose r1 for its register, presumably bad things would happen.

Comment: I actually include the clobber (didn't add here for simplicity), but it changes nothing: I still have an error. I have looked at disassembly: there is the same code generated in the both cases

Comment: While an ARM person might happen along any minute, since I'm here, perhaps you can describe what you think `vld1.32 q4,[%[input]],r1` is going to do.  Isn't a.x just going to be a number (ie not an address)?  If it were (say) 22, that would mean that `"+r" (a.x)` would move 22 into a general purpose register (maybe r3).  Doing `vld1.32 q4,[r3],r1` in the x86 world would look like you were reading into q4 from address 22 (offset 64 bytes), which is probably not a valid memory location. Perhaps you meant (&a.x)?

Comment: I just want to load four floats from a to q4 vector and add an offset to the address to load the next four float to another vector register in the next step (missed here for simplicity). I tried &a.x, but the compiler generates "Invalid lvalue in asm output".

Comment: I would add that in ARM the offset is just added to the general purpose register (reading into q4 with no offset). So as far as I understand it should be a valid memory location

Comment: I just realized that I load value from a.x to the general register instead of address. Thank you for your help